# Error when deploying my app to shiny server

Tags: deployment, shiny

I have created a shiny app on my computer that runs with no error. Now, I deployed the same app to the shiny server we have in our organization, and i cannot initiate the app. I receive the following error message:

transpose listening on http://127.0.0.1:43202
Warning: Error in tabPanel: argument "tabName" is missing, with no default
  65: tabPanel

Execution halted

here are my questions:
(1) I do use shinydashboard and shinydashboardplus libraries in my app and both are installed on the shiny server as well so this shouldnt be a problem since tabsetPanel and tabPanel are in these libraries, correct?

(2) tabPanel and tabSetPanel do NOT have a tabName argument. so what is this error specially because the app does work on my computer with no issue.

I know probably I need to provide the code but I cannot at the moment unless i significantly take stuff out of it (government property) but I was hoping someone can help considering the fact that it works on my computer but it doesnt when i deploy it.

Just a quick note that the R version installed on my laptop is 3.5.2 but the one on the server is 3.6! can this be an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a library bs4Dash was masking tabSetPanel which is quite confusing because i didnt have that problem running the app on my laptop...